# Azure DevOps RestAPI to change the User Access Level

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, rest

I'm working on an automation to update the access level of the user from Basic to stakeholder using an Azure DevOps RestAPI.

I have tried following Rest API as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/update%20user%20entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) but getting bad request.

https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxx/_apis/userentitlements/d42xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx?api-version=6.0-preview.3

Input Json:

```
{
    "from": "",
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/accessLevel",
    "value": {
      "accountLicenseType": "stakeholder",
      "licensingSource": "account"
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the body of the request you send is a JSON object, but the [example in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/update%20user%20entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples) specifies the body as JSON ***array***. Not sure if it's a strict requirement, but try wrapping the body into `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following body which should work as expected.

```
[
    {
        "from":"",
        "op":"replace",
        "path":"/accessLevel",
        "value":{
            "accountLicenseType":"stakeholder",
            "licensingSource":"account"
        }
    }
]
```

See: [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/update%20user%20entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples) for more details.